# Searching for all matches in texts with Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nlp

I have a list of particular words ('tokens') and need to find all of them (if any of them are present) in plain texts. I prefer using Pandas, to load text and perform the search. I'm using pandas as my collection of short text are timestamped and it is quite easy to organise these short text in a single data structure as pandas.

**For example:**

Consider a collection of fetched twitters uploaded in Pandas:

```
                                              twitts
0                       today is a great day for BWM
1                    prices of german cars increased
2             Japan introduced a new model of Toyota
3  German car makers, such as BMW, Audi and VW mo...
```

and a list of car makers:

```
list_of_car_makers = ['BMW', 'Audi','Mercedes','Toyota','Honda', 'VW']
```

Ideally, I need to get the following data frame:

```
                                              twitts  cars_mentioned
0                       today is a great day for BMW  [BMW]
1                    prices of german cars increased  []
2             Japan introduced a new model of Toyota  [Toyota]
3  German car makers, such as BMW, Audi and VW mo...  [BMW, Audi, VW]
```

I'm very new to NLP and text mining methods, and I read/search on the internet a lot of materials on that topic. My guess is that I can use `regex` and use `re.findall()`, but then I need to iterate over the list of tokens (car makers) the entire dataframe.

Are there more succinct ways of doing this simple task, especially with Panads?

Comment: Why downvote? If you think the question should be closed, write a comment, explaining that.

Comment: Have you seen pandas [str methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)?

Comment: @Alex, partially, mostly used `str.startswith()/str.contains()` and similar. Will read about them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pandas [`.str` methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) particularly [`.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html#pandas.Series.str.findall):

```
df['cars_mentioned'] = df['twitts'].str.findall('|'.join(list_of_car_makers))
```

Comment: oh gosh, so stupid of me. Pandas are so great! Many thanks.

Comment: ‘|’.join(list_of_car_makers)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df['cars_mentioned'] = df['twitts'].apply(lambda x: [c for c in list_of_car_makers if c in x])
```

Comment: @Ghilas BELHADJ, great answer thanks, but the solution of Alex is faster.

Comment: @ArnoldKlein Alex's answer is great too, but I don't know how did you get that it is faster than mine. When I timed it on 10k iterations, my solution is 0.5 secs faster.

Comment: That's interesting, I will investigate it. Will get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` and `filter`.

```
list(filter((lambda x: re.findall(x, twitt)), list_of_car_makers))
```

**Python sample**:

```
list_of_car_makers = ['BMW', 'Audi','Mercedes','Toyota','Honda', 'VW']

def cars_mentioned(twitt):
        return list(filter((lambda x: re.findall(x, twitt)), list_of_car_makers))

cars_mentioned('German car makers, such as BMW, Audi and VW mo...') >> ['BMW', 'Audi', 'VW']
```